# In Java, why are cookies added to the response and not the request?

Tags: java, cookies, request, token, interceptor

I noticed our code is adding the access token / authorization token to the response in the form of a cookie, using
`((HttpServletResponse) response).addCookie(accessTokenCookie);`

I've done some research and discovered this info:

> Request cookies are the cookies sent from browser to server

> Response cookies are the cookies sent out (from server to browser).

If this is the case, wouldn't my request interceptor / doFilterInternal need to apply the access token cookie to the request before it goes through, and not the response?

What makes it more confusing is the access token cookie is being created by fetching the access token value using request.getAttribute. If the request already has the access token as an attribute, why does a cookie needed to be added to the response?

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstand how cookies work.

The browser sends a request to some resource on some server.

The server returns the bytes that comprise the resource.

That's the basic flow. Now, let's talk about cookies:

When the server returns those bytes, it can send headers along with it. It is in fact required; for example, to talk about what the data is representing. For example, if you ask for `/img/background.png`, the server returns the image data and also sends `Content-Type: image/png`. Because browsers don't actually do the whole 'extensions indicate what the data is' thing, that's what that Content-Type header is for.

One of those headers is a `Set-Cookie` header.

Set-Cookie headers tell the browser: Take this data and save it somewhere. Next time you load this resource, send it again. There's some control about when to send it (you can make a Set-Cookie header sent when the server reponds for request /foo/bar make the browser send that cookie back even when asking for /foo/baz, or e.g. when `foo.myserver.com` sends a cookie, it can tell the browser: Send that back also when requesting resources from `bar.myserver.com`. There are limits though; when setting a cookie when responding to a request on `myserver.com`, you can't tell the browser to send that back when sending to `google.com`. Browsers are complex beasts; they ship with a huge list of top-level-ish domains and won't let you do this.

You don't 'add' cookies to a 'request' - the request stuff (the data you can obtain from an `HttpServletRequest` object) is just representing what the browser sent the server. The model for HttpServletRequest/Response is strictly two phases: The browser sends a request, and the server responds. That's it. It's not a long conversation. Just one message each way, that is all you get.

So, you add a cookie to the 'response' which means that future requests made by that same browser will then send it in the 'request'.

Comment: "The browser returns the bytes that comprise the resource." - you surely meant "The server returns the bytes that comprise the resource."

Comment: Yup, my bad. Fixed the text.